# Ball does not bounce off the screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First, I'm sorry for my english.
I hope I can explain it correctly
In my game, the ball should bounce everywhere on the edge. From a video I have a code with the ball in the field should remain, however, the ball now jumps up and slides along the screen

I've tried the if statement, but I'm newbie and do not know if I got it right

```
public class Ball_Controller : MonoBehaviour
```

{
    [SerializeField] private float moveSpeed = 10f;

```
[SerializeField] private Vector2 startDirection;

[SerializeField] private Vector2 startOtherDirection;

private Rigidbody2D rb;

public static bool GameIsover;
public GameObject gameOverUI;


public Transform topLeft;
public Transform bottomRight;





private void Start()
{



    GameIsover = false;

}
void Update()
{
    BallMove();


    transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, topLeft.position.x, bottomRight.position.x), Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y, bottomRight.position.y, topLeft.position.y), transform.position.z);
    if (transform.position.y == Screen.height || transform.position.x == Screen.width)
    {

        BallMoveOther();
    }





    if (GameIsover)
        return;

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
    {
        EndGame();


    }



}



void EndGame()
{

    Debug.Log("Game Over");
    GameIsover = true;
    gameOverUI.SetActive(true);
    Time.timeScale = 0;


}



private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag.Equals ("Player"))
    {

        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        Destroy(gameObject);
        EndGame();
    }




}

private void BallMove()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    rb.velocity = moveSpeed * startDirection;
}
private void BallMoveOther()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    rb.velocity = moveSpeed * startOtherDirection;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with code below,

```
transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, topLeft.position.x, bottomRight.position.x), Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y, bottomRight.position.y, 
topLeft.position.y), transform.position.z);

if (transform.position.y == Screen.height || transform.position.x == Screen.width){
    BallMoveOther();
}
```

1. Avoid using separate objects for finding the screen bounds
2. In the if statement transform.position.y is a global position, while screen.height is not.

Try something like this:

```
// Converting Screen positions to world space
Vector3 screenStart = Camera.main.ScreentoWorldPoint(new Vector3(0,0,0));
Vector3 screenEnd = Camera.main.ScreentoWorldPoint(new Vector3(screen.width,screen.height,0));

// Clampping the sprite within the screen
transform.position = new Vector3(
    Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x,screenStart.position.x,screenEnd.position.x),
    Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y,screenStart.position.y,screenEnd.position.y),
    transform.position.z);
// Getting the length and width of the sprite
Vector2 SpriteBnds = transform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.size;

// checking if the sprite went beyond the screen bounds in any four directions
if(
    transform.position.y+(SpriteBnds.y/2) >=screenEnd.position.y ||
    transform.position.y - (SpriteBnds.y/2) <= screenstart.position.y ||
    transform.position.x+(SpriteBnds.x/2) >=screenEnd.position.x ||
    transform.position.x - (SpriteBnds.x/2) <= screenstart.position.x)
    {
        BallMoveOther();
    }
```

Comment: hi thank you first for your quick reply. When I take over the script, my ball hangs in the lower left corner and stays there